# Updating MeteorJS accounts-password plugin

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am currently working on a profile page using the plugin "accounts-password" installed it via the command

```
meteor add accounts-password
```

I have run the program and so on and was able to add data; however, when I try to call or display the data on the browser using the

```
{{ currentUser.email }}
```

and

```
{{ currentUser.password }}
```

It doesn't display, but when I called

```
{{ currentUser.username }}
```

it works just fine. I tried to access the database via find().fetch(); and this is what I see.

```
id: "GP26SF2F8jmpqQuvT"
emails: Array[1]
      0: Object
        address: "testing@gmail.com"
      verified: false
      __proto__: Object
      length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
username: "testing"
__proto__: Object
```

Based on the arrangement, should I called the email as

```
{{ currentUser.emails.0.address }}
```

? Also I don't see the password in the data, is there a way to retrieve it? Actually my aim here to update the Meteor.users if user wants to change password or email address. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`accounts-password` doesn't publish the `password` field of the document by default. This is to be expected - for security reasons!

In regards to the email: `accounts` package allows the application to add multiple emails to a user. This is why there's an array of emails.

Instead of doing

```
{{ currentUser.emails.0.address }}
```

What you could do is add a helper to the template:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
   email: function(){
       return Meteor.user().emails[0].address;
   }
});
```

And then you can just use this in the template:

```
{{ email }}
```

> Actually my aim here to update the Meteor.users if user wants to change password or email address. Thanks.

I'd say that there's almost never a reason to publish the user's password to the client. It's a huge security risk. The `accounts-password` package has taken care of the common use-cases, so you can just use [`Accounts.changePassword()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_changepassword) on the client to allow the user to change their password.

If you want to allow the user to change their email, what you want to do, is use a [Method](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods). A method can be called by the client, but the code is executed on the server. After it's executed, the server returns a response to the client. Kind of like how HTTP works.

In this case, the client could call a method named `changeEmail`, which tries to change the user's email. If all checks pass etc, the server changes the user's email and returns a response, e.g. `"success"`, otherwise returns `"fail"`. This is what the code could look like:

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
    Meteor.call('changeEmail', newEmail, function(error, response){
        if(error){
            console.error(error);
        } else {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}

if(Meteor.isServer){
    Meteor.methods({
        changeEmail: function(newEmail){
            Accounts.addEmail(this.userId, newEmail, false);
            var userEmails = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId, {fields: {emails: 1}}).emails;
            if(userEmails.length > 1){
                Accounts.removeEmail(this.userId, userEmails[0].address);
                Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(this.userId, newEmail);
                return "success";
            } else {
                throw new Meteor.Error('fail', 'email not correct!');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

If you're not familiar with Methods, you can read either [this](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/security-with-methods) tutorial by Meteor or [this](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/meteor-methods-client-side-operations/) article. Also, my code might not be 100% functional, it's just an example.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice, I will surely read it . . about the displaying the email, when I do it like this:

{{ currentUser.emails.0.address }}

It gives an error

Comment: @Neil what you could do is add a helper to the template. e.g. `Template.myTemplate.helpers({
      email: function(){
          return Meteor.user().emails[0].address;
      }
 });`, then you can just do `{{email}}`

Comment: About the email address update, I followed your advice and did the method. What the code does based on the result is it will remove the current email by using `Accounts.removeEmail(this.userId, userEmails[0]);` and then adds the new one making the new email to be the index[0] after the old email is removed. However, in my test it did add the email but the old email is still there.

Comment: @Neil yeah, I didn't test the code. You need to do `Accounts.removeEmail(this.userId, userEmails[0].address);`

Comment: The same result with `Accounts.removeEmail(this.userId, userEmails[0].address);` . .

It is either the problem:

`var userEmails = Meteor.users.find(this.userId, {fields: {emails: 1}});`

or

`Accounts.removeEmail(this.userId, userEmails[0].address);`

Comment: Maybe it can not find the right email index that is why it can not delete or remove the email.

In the server side, it says "test@gmail.com" verfied: false

Comment: @Neil Make sure you use `findOne` not `find`. `find` returns a cursor, `findOne` returns a document. And the `.emails` part at the end of `findOne` is pretty important as well.

Comment: . Finally! :) case closed . . thank you so much . . it sorted out now . . I should have reset the database . . the account I was using contains 2 email address that was the cause of the error . . :)

Comment: By the way, the one you provided above is the exact format that worked :)